# Pass requests for specified hosts throw VM

Tags: nginx, virtual-machines, redirect

I have VPN that restrict all internet except inner resources. I don't like it and i want to   install VM, connect it to VPN and redirect all requests for specified hosts to VM and get back answer.
Is it possible with nginx or something?
I need to use windows as main OS because of work software.